# singletons in cocoa, are they evil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I have seen lot of "singletons are evil" in this site.
It almost make me believe singletons are pathological liars. 
But,
If it's true, why there are so many singletons in cocoa? Like shareApplication, shareManager, and more.
And I'm wonder that if I don't use singleton pattern, how can I do the same things like it. For example, ensure there is only one instance and access it when i need.

So I will doubt the saying until I can figure out there is a better way.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: well, [Singletons **are** pathological liars](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/17/singletons-are-pathological-liars/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no a single feature or pattern that is inherently evil. Even `goto` has its use and can sometimes improve readability. "Singletons are evil" comes from the fact that many novice developers are prone to misuse of them. So this is a common sense and sometimes common sense isn't the best solution.

In your examples `shared...` are not technically singletons. You can create thousands instances of `UIApplication` or `NSFileManager` at the same time. They are more like service locators ("find me my application", "find me a default file manager"). These methods provide us with some useful shared values we need 99% of time. Though this can make unit testing harder benefits are worth it.

Comment: Thanks so much, and I agree with u that these methods they are so convient  that i'd rather ignore the problems they created. But, this put me to thinking of the global variable, i used to think they are convient, however, turn out to be misunderstanding. Now your answer have added to my confusion. is that mean, nothings is evil, even like global variable or goto. it's seem like that my college tutor taught totally wrong...(he just told me singletons are evil..)

Comment: @lancy Well, I can't tell if your tutor was wrong because I don't know exact context in which they said it. As for degrees of evil - it's like speech or literature. F-words are "evil". If you speak constantly using f-words words the quality of your language is lower - people can't tell if you want to say something or just swearing. But in some situations such words help you to get things done (think of the battlefield orders). It sort of the same thing with features/patterns and people who have to read and maintain their usage.

Comment: @lancy: Singletons are global objects. http://boredzo.org/blog/archives/2011-03-18/application-delegate-singletons

Answer (score 0):

Singletons are generally helpful to store your global data on.

However Singletons are usually just used as a junkyard for all kinds of random methods and variables without any order or reason.

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx

This is probably why people dislike the use of them Singletons.

If you don't misuse the Singleton with chaotic behavior then you shouldn't avoid using it in my opinion.

Comment: Kind of a different problem: You're talking about the “Big Ball of Mud”/“God Object” class. This can be done as a singleton or just a bunch of class methods (or, in fact, even in a regular object—it's a common problem in controllers). And, as you say, it is possible to make a singleton that isn't a Big Ball of Mud.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many singletons in Cocoa because it was designed long before it was cool to declare “evil” and “considered harmful” on everything one had problems with.

Singletons are not totally evil. They work pretty well in many situations when used right. You've found out about the problems associated with them, but it does not mean you have to get rid of them immediately otherwise the world will end. The realities of some projects are such so you won't ever experience problems of singletons.

Obviously you can't avoid using library singletons when they already exist. Whenever you need a certain object like NSApplication or NSWorkspace, you should use their sharedApplication/sharedWorkspace methods, that's how system frameworks were designed.

When designing your own code, instead of singletons you can make sure that objects are only created by factories, and code some factory methods in a way so that they return previous instance if this kind of object was requested before. This design avoids typical disadvantage of globals and singletons of being unable to substitute mocks instead of them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I think you mean that singleton pattern isn't evil, but isn't good enough. and just because cocoa hardly go wrong, so we can simply use it. but when designing my own code, I'd better use factory pattern instand of singletons to avoids the problems? It's that mean, factory is better then singletons? And maybe someday it will be deprecated like the global variable? Thanks again!

Comment: @lancy: The factory pattern (creating objects to create objects) is a waste of time and effort all around. Avoid it. Enforced singletons are generally a waste of time and effort to implement, but not to use, and there are cases where they are appropriate. Usually you should not implement a singleton at all, not even “return previous instance”—not because it's harmful, but just because there's no reason to do that. If you don't need more than one, then just don't create more than one.